# convert date to milliseconds in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is it possible to convert date to milliseconds?
From below type(Table) when i want retrieve data of JoinDate column should show time in total Milliseconds.

Example
2010-10-12 13:10:10 (Time)==>1291966810000(Millisecond)

```
 ----------------------------------
|S.No | ID   |  JoinDate          |
 ----------------------------------
| 1   | N107 | 2010-10-12 13:10:10 |
|     |      |                     |
| 2   | N108 | 2011-2-12 10:40:10  |
|     |      |                     |
| 3   | N109 | 2013-10-12 11:10:50 |
|     |      |                     |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: So what you are asking is whether it is possible to convert an SQL date into a date field expressed in milliseconds when exporting your data from an SQL DB into Elasticsearch?

Comment: no i need to get milliseconds when we are fetching data from elastic search table @Val

Comment: Can you update your question with the current query you have? Eventually also your mapping type configuration?

Answer (score 7):

try something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "JoinDate": {
      "script": "doc['JoinDate'].date.getMillis()"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer covers lang. painless. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "createddate": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "script": "doc['createddate'].value.millis"
    }
  }
}
```